# How to find Mahalanobis distance between two 1D arrays in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have two 1D arrays, and I need to find out the Mahalanobis distance between them.

Array 1

```
-0.125510275,0.067021735,0.140631825,-0.014300184,-0.122152582,0.002372072,-0.050777748,-0.106606245,0.149123222,-0.159149423,0.210138127,0.031959131,-0.068411253,-0.038253143,-0.024590122,0.101361006,-0.160774037,-0.183688596,-0.07163775,-0.096662685,-0.000117288,0.14251323,-0.030461289,-0.006710192,-0.217195332,-0.338565469,-0.030219197,-0.100772612,0.144092739,-0.092911556,-0.008420993,0.042907588,-0.212668449,-0.009366207,-7.01E-05,0.134508118,-0.015715659,-0.050884761,0.18804647,0.04946585,-0.242626131,0.099951334,0.053660966,0.275807977,0.216019884,-0.009127878,0.019819722,-0.043750495,0.12940146,-0.259942383,0.061821692,0.107142501,0.098196507,0.022301452,0.079412982,-0.131031215,-0.049483716,0.126781181,-0.195536733,0.077051811,0.061049294,-0.039563753,0.02573989,0.025330214,0.204785526,0.099218346,-0.050533134,-0.109173119,0.205652237,-0.168003649,-0.062734045,0.100320764,-0.063513778,-0.120843001,-0.223983109,0.075016715,0.481291831,0.107607022,-0.141365036,0.075003348,-0.042418435,-0.041501854,0.096700639,0.083469011,-0.033227846,-0.050748199,-0.045331556,0.065955319,0.26927036,0.082820699,-0.014033476,0.176714703,0.042264186,-0.011814327,0.041769091,-0.00132945,-0.114337325,-0.013483777,-0.111367472,-0.051828772,-0.022199111,0.030011443,0.015529033,0.171916366,-0.172722578,0.214662731,-0.0219073,-0.067695767,0.040487193,0.04814541,0.003313571,-0.01360167,0.115932293,-0.235844463,0.185181856,0.130868644,0.010789306,0.171733275,0.059378762,0.003508842,0.039326921,0.024174646,-0.195897669,-0.088932432,0.025385177,-0.134177506,0.08158315,0.049005955
```

And, Array 2

```
-0.120652862,0.030241199,0.146165773,-0.044423241,-0.138606027,-0.048646796,-0.00780057,-0.101798892,0.185339138,-0.210505784,0.1637595,0.015000292,-0.10359703,0.102251172,-0.043159217,0.183324724,-0.171825036,-0.173819616,-0.112194099,-0.161590934,-0.002507193,0.163269699,-0.037766434,0.041060638,-0.178659558,-0.268946916,-0.055348843,-0.11808344,0.113775767,-0.073903576,-0.039505914,0.032382272,-0.159118786,0.007761603,0.057116233,0.043675732,-0.057895001,-0.104836114,0.22844176,0.055832602,-0.245030299,0.006276659,0.140012532,0.21449241,0.159539059,-0.049584024,0.016899824,-0.074179329,0.119686954,-0.242336214,-0.001390997,0.097442642,0.059720818,0.109706804,0.073196828,-0.16272822,0.022305552,0.102650747,-0.192103565,0.104134969,0.099571452,-0.101140082,-0.038911857,0.071292967,0.202927336,0.12729995,-0.047885433,-0.165100336,0.220239595,-0.19612211,-0.075948663,0.096906625,-0.07410948,-0.108219706,-0.155030385,-0.042231761,0.484629512,0.093194947,-0.105109185,0.072906494,-0.056871444,-0.057923764,0.101847053,0.092042476,-0.061295755,-0.031595342,-0.01854251,0.074671492,0.266587347,0.052284949,0.003548023,0.171518356,0.053180017,-0.022400264,0.061757766,0.038441688,-0.139473096,-0.05759665,-0.101672307,-0.074863717,-0.02349415,-0.011674869,0.010008151,0.141401738,-0.190440938,0.216421023,-0.028323224,-0.078021556,-0.011468113,0.100600921,-0.019697987,-0.014288296,0.114862509,-0.162037179,0.171686187,0.149788797,-0.01235011,0.136169329,0.008751356,0.024811052,0.003802934,0.00500867,-0.1840965,-0.086204343,0.018549766,-0.110649876,0.068768717,0.03012047
```

I found that Scipy has already implemented the [function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.mahalanobis.html). However, I am confused about what the value of IV should be. I tried to do the following

```
V = np.cov(np.array([array_1, array_2]))
IV = np.linalg.inv(V)
print(mahalanobis(array_1, array_2, IV))
```

But, I get the following error:

> File
>   "C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\face\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\distance.py",
>   line 1043, in mahalanobis
>           m = np.dot(np.dot(delta, VI), delta)
>
> ValueError: shapes (128,) and (2,2) not aligned: 128 (dim 0) != 2 (dim 0)

**EDIT:**

```
array_1 = [-0.10577646642923355, 0.09617947787046432, 0.029290344566106796, 0.02092641592025757, -0.021434104070067406, -0.13410840928554535, 0.028282659128308296, -0.12082239985466003, 0.21936850249767303, -0.06512433290481567, 0.16812698543071747, -0.03302834928035736, -0.18088334798812866, -0.04598559811711311, -0.014739632606506348, 0.06391328573226929, -0.15650317072868347, -0.13678401708602905, 0.01166679710149765, -0.13967938721179962, 0.14632365107536316, 0.025218486785888672, 0.046839646995067596, 0.09690812975168228, -0.13414686918258667, -0.2883925437927246, -0.1435326784849167, -0.17896348237991333, 0.10746842622756958, -0.09142691642045975, 0.04860316216945648, 0.031577128916978836, -0.17280976474285126, -0.059613555669784546, -0.05718057602643967, 0.0401446670293808, 0.026440180838108063, -0.017025159671902657, 0.22091664373874664, 0.024703698232769966, -0.15607595443725586, -0.0018572667613625526, -0.037675946950912476, 0.3210170865058899, 0.10884962230920792, 0.030370134860277176, 0.056784629821777344, -0.030112050473690033, 0.023124486207962036, -0.1449904441833496, 0.08885903656482697, 0.17527811229228973, 0.08804896473884583, 0.038310401141643524, -0.01704210229218006, -0.17355971038341522, -0.018237406387925148, 0.030551932752132416, -0.23085585236549377, 0.13475817441940308, 0.16338199377059937, -0.06968289613723755, -0.04330683499574661, 0.04434924200177193, 0.22637797892093658, 0.07463733851909637, -0.15070196986198425, -0.07500549405813217, 0.10863590240478516, -0.22288714349269867, 0.0010778247378766537, 0.057608842849731445, -0.12828609347343445, -0.17236559092998505, -0.23064571619033813, 0.09910193085670471, 0.46647992730140686, 0.0634111613035202, -0.13985536992549896, 0.052741192281246185, -0.1558966338634491, 0.022585246711969376, 0.10514408349990845, 0.11794176697731018, -0.06241249293088913, 0.06389056891202927, -0.14145469665527344, 0.060088545083999634, 0.09667345881462097, -0.004665130749344826, -0.07927791774272919, 0.21978208422660828, -0.0016187895089387894, 0.04876316711306572, 0.03137822449207306, 0.08962501585483551, -0.09108036011457443, -0.01795950159430504, -0.04094596579670906, 0.03533276170492172, 0.01394269522279501, -0.08244197070598602, -0.05095399543642998, 0.04305890575051308, -0.1195211187005043, 0.16731074452400208, 0.03894471749663353, -0.0222858227789402, -0.07944411784410477, 0.0614166259765625, -0.1481470763683319, -0.09113290905952454, 0.14758692681789398, -0.24051085114479065, 0.164126917719841, 0.1753545105457306, -0.003193420823663473, 0.20875433087348938, 0.03357946127653122, 0.1259773075580597, -0.00022807717323303223, -0.039092566817998886, -0.13582147657871246, -0.01937306858599186, 0.015938198193907738, 0.00787206832319498, 0.05792934447526932, 0.03294186294078827]
array_2 = [-0.1966051608324051, 0.0940953716635704, -0.0031937970779836178, -0.03691547363996506, -0.07240629941225052, -0.07114037871360779, -0.07133384048938751, -0.1283963918685913, 0.15377545356750488, -0.091400146484375, 0.10803385823965073, -0.09235749393701553, -0.1866973638534546, -0.021168243139982224, -0.09094691276550293, 0.07300164550542831, -0.20971564948558807, -0.1847742646932602, -0.009817334823310375, -0.05971141159534454, 0.09904412180185318, 0.0278592761605978, -0.012554554268717766, 0.09818517416715622, -0.1747943013906479, -0.31632938981056213, -0.0864541232585907, -0.13249783217906952, 0.002135572023689747, -0.04935726895928383, 0.010047778487205505, 0.04549024999141693, -0.26334646344184875, -0.05263081565499306, -0.013573898002505302, 0.2042253464460373, 0.06646320968866348, 0.08540669083595276, 0.12267164140939713, -0.018634958192706108, -0.19135263562202454, 0.01208433136343956, 0.09216200560331345, 0.2779296934604645, 0.1531585156917572, 0.10681629925966263, -0.021275708451867104, -0.059720948338508606, 0.06610126793384552, -0.21058350801467896, 0.005440462380647659, 0.18833838403224945, 0.08883830159902573, 0.025969548150897026, 0.0337764173746109, -0.1585341989994049, 0.02370697632431984, 0.10416869819164276, -0.19022507965564728, 0.11423652619123459, 0.09144753962755203, -0.08765758574008942, -0.0032832929864525795, -0.0051014479249715805, 0.19875964522361755, 0.07349056005477905, -0.1031823456287384, -0.10447365045547485, 0.11358538269996643, -0.24666038155555725, -0.05960353836417198, 0.07124857604503632, -0.039664581418037415, -0.20122921466827393, -0.31481748819351196, -0.006801256909966469, 0.41940364241600037, 0.1236235573887825, -0.12495145946741104, 0.12580059468746185, -0.02020396664738655, -0.03004150651395321, 0.11967054009437561, 0.09008713811635971, -0.07470540702342987, 0.09324200451374054, -0.13763070106506348, 0.07720538973808289, 0.19568027555942535, 0.036567769944667816, 0.030284458771348, 0.14119629561901093, -0.03820852190256119, 0.06232285499572754, 0.036639824509620667, 0.07704029232263565, -0.12276224792003632, -0.0035170004703104496, -0.13103705644607544, 0.027697769924998283, -0.01527332328259945, -0.04027168080210686, -0.03659897670149803, 0.03330300375819206, -0.12293602526187897, 0.09043421596288681, -0.019673841074109077, -0.07563626766204834, -0.13991905748844147, 0.014788001775741577, -0.07630413770675659, 0.00017269013915210962, 0.16345393657684326, -0.25710681080818176, 0.19869503378868103, 0.19393865764141083, -0.07422225922346115, 0.19553625583648682, 0.09189949929714203, 0.051557887345552444, -0.0008843056857585907, -0.006250975653529167, -0.1680600494146347, -0.10320111364126205, 0.03232177346944809, -0.08931156992912292, 0.11964476853609085, 0.00814182311296463]
```

The co-variance matrix of the above arrays turn out to be a singular matrix, and thus I am unable to inverse it. Why does it end up being a singular matrix?

**EDIT 2: Solution**

Since the co-variance matrix here is singular matrix, I had to pseudo inverse it using `np.linalg.pinv(V)`.

Comment: `IV` is supposed to be the inverse of the covariance matrix of the 128-dimensional distribution from where the vectors are sampled. You can make an estimation of the covariance matrix with `V = np.cov(np.array([array_1, array_2]).T)` (in `np.cov` rows are variables and columns observations), but it would only use those two samples. Ideally you would use a better estimate, like the covariance matrix of a whole dataset.

Comment: @jdehesa  I don't have a distribution from which I pull the 128-dimensional arrays, These are values generated from an image. Basically an encoding of a face. When I try out the `.T` as you have mentioned above, I get the error while trying to inverse the Co-variance matrix, `numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix`.

Comment: You just have to take the transpose of the array before you calculate the covariance. And @jdehesa is right, calculating covariance from two observations is a bad idea. First, you should calculate `cov` using the entire image. You can then find the Mahalanobis distance between any two rows using that same covariance matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`numpy.cov` docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html#numpy-cov), the first argument should be an array `m` such that:

> Each row of m represents a variable, and each column a single observation of all those variables.

So to fix your code just take the transpose (with `.T`) of your array before you call `cov`:

```
V = np.cov(np.array([array_1, array_2]).T)
IV = np.linalg.inv(V)
print(mahalanobis(array_1, array_2, IV))
```

I just tested this out on some random data, and I can confirm it works.

Also, calculating covariance from just two observations is a bad idea, and not likely to be very accurate. If your data is coming from an image, you should use the entire image `img` (or at least the entire region of interest) when calculating the covariance matrix, then use that matrix to find the Mahalanobis distance between the two vectors of interest:

```
V = np.cov(np.array(img))
IV = np.linalg.inv(V)
print(mahalanobis(array_1, array_2, IV))
```

You may or may not need to replace `img` with `img.T`, depending on how you generated `array_1` and `array_2` in the first place.

If you're getting singular covariance matrices, what you have is a math problem, not a code problem. It's apparently a common enough problem that the question ["why is my covariance matrix singular?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/70899/4894) has already been asked and answered. Very broadly, it seems like it can happen when enough of your data points are "too similar", in some sense. I'd imagine using just two data points also makes this more likely.

Comment: Can you try this out with the arrays that I have mentioned. Since `np.array(img)` is not actually what I need. The arrays that I have mentioned are the ones that I need to use, and they are generated after much calculations on two different images. I am actually getting an error when using the arrays that I have mentioned. Error: `numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix`

Comment: For what it's worth, another thing to note is that, `array_1` and `array_2` are from different images.

Comment: Nevermind. It's actually working for the data that I have given, but giving the above error for another array pair. Thanks. It you are interested to look into this pair, I'll just update the question.

Comment: @ParthapratimNeog I added a link to my answer with a very in depth discussion of why covar matrices end up being singular. If I were you, I'd find a way to calculate the covar using more than two data points. It'll probably end up being the easiest fix.